# HTTPS on Fargate's public IP - is it possible?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I run a service on Fargate and my main objective is to keep the cost as low as possible. A minor downtime is not an issue which is helpful with the current approach. I have one instance of the task, running on Fargate (with spot provider). I have my domain under route53 and i'm using a lambda function for updating the A Record of www when a new container starts. Everything seems to be working fine. I need to enable HTTPS though and i'm stuck with this one - don't know if it's possible. I created a (free) certificate by AWS but i don't know how to make the service to listen on port 443 (allowed in SG). Using a Load Balancer is not an option as it will automatically increase the cost by ~15$.

Is this possible? Maybe i just need to modify the container (using apache)?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, but you will need to look into something like Let's Encrypt for an SSL certificate you can use directly inside the Fargate instance. ACM certificates cannot be used for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Configure you webserver inside the container with cert and private key as normal to listen on 443 [1](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html). Container hosted on Fargate with public IP is not much different than an EC2 instance with public IP. You are already taking care of the update to A record if it changes.